# Rails 3.x startup error on Dreamhost - session_store.rb issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, dreamhost

Here's another Rails-on-Dreamhost installation error.

- Used DH's own "getting started" wiki page. No issue getting initial "Welcome aboard" message.
- Local app created using mysql. Gems frozen during creation. DBs created on Dreamhost w/o apparent issue.
- Used "bundle install" / "bundle package" on DH get gems into correct locations
- Downgraded the rake gem to v0.8.7 to solve first hiccup.
- Rack complained on startup: "...config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end"
- session_store.rb shown below. Untouched from original build:
  App02::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app02_session'

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Ruby less than 1.9 which doesn't support the new hash key syntax:
{ key: value }. Upgrade to Ruby 1.9+ and that should fix your issue.

Comment: Stephen, you're probably right. However I haven't figured out how to upgrade Ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 on a DreamHost shared-server account. (I'm not sudo'd.) Bummer.